# Linq Nested List 3 deep

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have created 2 level nested linq query as:

```
var data = (from p in Departments
            join e in Employees on p.Id equals e.EmpId into emp
            select new { p,emp }).ToList().Dump();
```

**Result**

`Department
    - EmpName
    - EmpName
Department
    - EmpName
    - EmpName`

I need to add another level to get each employees DateWorked List.

Here is how the end query result should look like:

`Department
    - EmpName
          -DateWorked
          -DateWorked
    - EmpName
          -DateWorked
          -DateWorked
Department
    - EmpName
          -DateWorked
          -DateWorked
    - EmpName
          -DateWorked
          -DateWorked`

How can I add to my current query to get the 3rd nested list using Linq?

Answer (score 2):

You can do an inner query:

```
var data = (
from p in Departments
join e in Employees on p.Id equals e.DeptId into emp
select new {p, employees=(from s in emp
                          join d in DateWorked on s.Id equals d.EmpId into dts
                          select new {s, dts})   
           }).ToList().Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx), and then just query telling it what you want:

```
var data=db.Departments
  .Include(d=>Employees)
  .Include(d=>Employees.Select(e=>e.DatesWorked))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Well, that is supposing the OP is using EF ;). Another thing is the first include is not necessary, the second one includes both nav properties.

Comment: @octavioccl Yes, the second `.Include` does implicitly include both, but I usually mention both.  It makes it explicitly clear what I am looking for, and I find it more maintainable.  For example, if we no longer need DatesWorked, you just remove that include, where if you depended on it also including Employees, then your code breaks (or causes a 1+N query).  LINQ2SQL has similar capability with `LoadWith`, nHibernate with `Fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var customers = context.Customers
            .Include(i => i.Invoices)
                .ThenInclude(it => it.Items))
            .ToList();
}
```

More
https://entityframework.net/include-multiple-levels